# Styles are not applied to HTML element after dynamically inserted to DOM - Angular

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, sass

I wanted to add an "i" element as a child element to HTMLDivElement
but styles are not applied to the newly inserted "i" element.

How can I make sure to apply the same styles to newly added "i" element?
I want to apply the the styles that I have set in the scss file for the new element.
(when I am inserting the new element in the .ts file, I can set the same styles using JS(TS), but I intend to use the scss/css styles, is there any way to use the scss/css styles for the newly added elements?)

accommodation-view-data.html

```
<div class="star-rating" #starRating>
  <i class="bi bi-star-fill"></i> <!-- styles are applied to this element successfully -->
</div>
```

accommodation-view-data.component.scss

```
i{
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  padding: 0 0.25rem ;
  color: #ffbe0f;
}
```

accommodation-view-data.component.ts

```
import {AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-accommodation-view-data',
  templateUrl: './accommodation-view-data.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./accommodation-view-data.component.scss']
})
export class AccommodationViewDataComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('starRating')
  starRatingElem!: ElementRef;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    /* When I append the the new element to the DOM,
    * the styles that I have set in the scss file, are not applied for the new element */
    const starIconElement = document.createElement('i');
    starIconElement.classList.add('bi');
    starIconElement.classList.add('bi-star-fill');
    (this.starRatingElem.nativeElement as HTMLDivElement).append(starIconElement);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a normal behavior, When you write style that is integrated in the styleUrls, every single class is reworked to be specific to the component, it's the style scope (note the `i[ng-content-lep-c52]`in the screenshot below).

So adding an element in the dom like you do is not recommended, instead prefer toggling it thanks to a ngIf or here for stars with a ngFor or else you'll have hard times trying to make it dynamic and bind values with the component model.

Like you can see in this screenshot, the first element is properly matched with the scoped style while the new element isn't.

**NOT RECOMMENDED AND DEPRECATED**: To bypass this you can use the `::ng-deep` pseudo class to make a style global, and therefor getting overrided by scoped style as you can see in this screenshot comming from this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vgfl2z?file=src/app/app.component.css).

You can find more information about styles in angular [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles)
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: @Dhanusha_Perera07 if this answer satisfied your need, you can upvote and accept it,thank you